# Show that $\varphi(x)=x(1)+x(2)$ and $ \psi(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x(k)}{k}$ are continuos and linear

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification

> Show that $$\varphi:\ell^2\to\mathbb R, \varphi(x)=x(1)+x(2)$$ and $$\psi:\ell^1\to\mathbb R, \psi(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x(k)}{k}$$ are continuos and bounded

Linearity is straight forward we have $x,y\in\ell^2, \alpha\in\mathbb R$
$$\varphi(\alpha x+y)=\alpha (x(1)+x(2)) + y(1)+y(2) = \alpha\varphi(x)+\varphi(y)$$ and for $x,y\in\ell^1,\alpha\in\mathbb R$
$$\psi(\alpha x+y) = \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\alpha x(k)+y(k)}{k}=\alpha\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x(k)}{k}+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{y(k)}{k}=\alpha\psi(x)+\psi(y).$$

> Now does it suffice to show that the operator norms $\|\varphi\|,\|\psi\|$ are bounded to show continuity?

The operator norm for $\varphi$ is $\|\varphi\|=\sup\limits_{\|x\|_{\ell^2}\leqslant 1}|\varphi(x)|=\sup\limits_{\|x\|_{\ell^2}=1}|\varphi(x)|$ furthermore $$\|x\|_{\ell^2}=\sqrt{\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty|x(k)|^2} = 1 \iff \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty|x(k)|^2 =1$$
from which follow that $\|\varphi\|=\sqrt2$ for $x = \left\lbrace\frac{\sqrt2}2,\frac{\sqrt2}2, 0, \dots\right\rbrace$.

The operator norm for $\psi$ is$\|\varphi\|=\sup\limits_{\|x\|_{\ell^1}\leqslant 1}|\psi(x)|=\sup\limits_{\|x\|_{\ell^1}=1}|\psi(x)|$ the $\ell^1$ norm is $1$ if $$\|x\|_{\ell^1}=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty|x(k)| = 1 \iff \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty|x(k)| $$ because $\psi$ penalizes larger elements in the series more than earlier ones the operator norm is $\|\psi\|=1$ for example with $x = \left\lbrace1, 0, \dots\right\rbrace$.

Is this correct?

Comment: By taking a special $x\neq0$, you showed that —for this particular $x$— the equality
$|\varphi(x)|=\sqrt2\Vert x\Vert$ holds.
It only proves that $\Vert\varphi\Vert\in[\sqrt2\mathbin;+\infty]$.
It happens that $\Vert\varphi\Vert=\sqrt2$.
To prove it, you might express $\varphi(x)$ as a scalar product $\langle x\mid a\rangle$ for some $a\in\ell^2(\Bbb{N})$…
Also, regarding $\psi$ it is defined by a series; at some point you'll have to be certain of its convergence.

Comment: @jpboucheron I maximised $a+b$ under the constraint that $a^2+b^2=1$ for $\|\psi\|$ does this work as well?

Comment: I understand but a priori you have maximize $\varphi\big((x_n)_n\big)$ under the constraint that $\sum_n x_n^2=1$.
Of course it amounts to the situation you describe, but some little extra explanation is necessary.
Back to my hint: $\varphi(x)=\langle x\mid a\rangle$, with $a=(1,1,0,\ldots,0,\ldots)$; also $\psi(x)=\langle x\mid b\rangle$ with $b=\big(0,1,\frac12,\cdots,\frac1n,\cdots\big)$.
Then you may use Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: @jpboucheron I See what you mean with the scalar products I will think about it some more. Thank you.